How to disable UIButton getting highlighted when clicked?
I tried multiple solutions from stack overflow but no luck. I have set HighlightedAdjustsImage = false
In my Code :
button.backgroundColor = .clear
button.layer.borderWidth = 0

inside my IBAction for button I am changing image and also setting value of isSelected as :
*button.isSelected = !button.isSelected*

Inside storyboard 
what did i do wrong here?

The problem is the Style setting of your button in the storyboard (the second popup menu in your screenshot).
Change the Style from Plain to Default and the button will start working according to your specification.


Try this
To disable the highlighting effect of a UIButton when it is clicked, you can set its showsTouchWhenHighlighted property to false. Here's how you can do it:
yourButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = false


Inside my storyboard I already disabled it

I also added it inside my IBOutlet code button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = false, but no luck. 'showsTouchWhenHighlighted' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration

@AppleDeveloper "This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration" That's the key.

I solved my issue by removing below code.
button.isSelected = !button.isSelected

Setting isSelected value is highlighting the button when clicked, removed it and added my own flag.

To disable the highlighting effect of a UIButton ,
please add the below extension in your code:
 class NoHighlightButton: UIButton {
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        get {
            return false
        }
        set {
            // Do nothing to prevent the default highlighting behavior
        }
    }
}

after that go to the interface builder and change the button class UIButton to NoHighlightButton. Your issue will be resolved.
